# is there any func to set extension=php_mssql.dll without editing in php.ini using functions like we used ini_set(); method

Tags: php, sql-server

```
<?php

  $con=mysql_connect('$url','$dbuser','$dbpass');

  if(!$con){
  die('cannot establish connection:'.mysql_error());
}
 $db=mysql_select_db("$db");
 if(!$db){
die('cannot found database:'.mysql_error());
 }
 ?>
```

Giving warnings :-

> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on
>   line 3
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: No such host is known. in D:\xampp\htdocs\connection.php on
>   line 3 cannot establish connection:php_network_getaddresses:
>   getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: [dl()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) but that isn't what's triggering these errors

Comment: Your problem here is using single quotes in your connect criteria: a value like `$url` in single quotes will be treated as a literal string `$url` not as a variable..... why are you quoting in the first place?

Comment: And you really shouldn't be using the MySQL extension anyway; start living in the 21st century, use MySQLi or PDO instead

Answer (score 0):

Use [dl()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php)

> `dl` — **Loads a PHP extension at runtime**

as well as use [`extension_loaded()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extension-loaded.php) to check extension is loaded

For `mssql` - `dl('php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll');`

[Example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php#refsect1-function.dl-examples)

```
<?php
// Example loading an extension based on OS
if (!extension_loaded('sqlite')) {
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') {
        dl('php_sqlite.dll');
    } else {
        dl('sqlite.so');
    }
}
```